# Rails count number of Users who favorited Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

Relatively new to rails, and am just trying to sort through my model relationships in order to find the number of users who have Favorited a particular post. Here are my models:

User.rb

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_posts, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Post'
```

Post.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorites
```

Favorite.rb

```
belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user
```

In my Posts#show view I want to call something like

```
<%= @post.favorited.count %>
```

and get the number of users who have favorited this post, but it tells me that this is an undefined method.

Any suggestions? thank you,

Comment: that's because `favorited` is not a `Post` method. try `@post.favorites.count` although I believe the `Post` model also needs `has_many :favorites, as: :favorited`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_posts, through: :favorites, 
                            source: :favorited, 
                            source_type: 'Post'
end

class Post
  has_many :favorites, as: :favorited
end

class Favorite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
end
```

This will let get a count through `@post.favorites.size` - but you should either use a join or [counter caches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) to avoid N+1 query issues.

```
class Favorite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks! this works!! (except that when I add "counter_cache: true" it no longer lets me favorite anything in the site

Answer (score 2):

@engineersmnky is right, you will need to include the relationship on Post as well.

Additionally while you can get this information via a join, it won't let you efficiently query the top favorited posts or include the number of favorites in a table of posts. You should persist the count each time a favorite is added or removed, either using [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) or a [counter cache](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/).